# JWT ERROR TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

Im trying to create an application with express and JWT (JsonWebToken). It works localy but when i try to use it on my server at home it gives an error. I spend like an hour trying to find a solution but nothing works.

```
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
    at Object.module.exports [as sign] (/home/container/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:108:58)
    at server.post (/home/container/server.js:51:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/container/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/container/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/container/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/container/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/container/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (/home/container/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/home/container/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at /home/container/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:137:5
```

It is a really a simple application but i can't find out why it gives the error above ^^

This is my code:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');




const server = express();
const port = 3000 || process.env.PORT;

server.options('*', cors());
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');


 server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});


const posts = [
    {
        user: 'david',
        title: 'post'
    },
    {
        user: 'bryan',
        title: 'post2'
    }
];



server.get('/posts', authenticateToken, (req, response) => {
 response.json(posts.filter(post => post.user === req.user));
});

server.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const {username, password} = req.body;
    if(username == null) return res.sendStatus(401);

    jwt.sign(username, 'test', (err, token) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.sendStatus(403);
        }
    
        console.log(accessToken);
        res.json({accessToken: accessToken});
    });
 });
  
   


function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];

    if(token == null) return res.sendStatus(401);
    jwt.verify(token, 'test', (err, user) => {
        if(err) return res.sendStatus(403);
        req.user = user;
        next();
    });
}
```

I cannot find a solution on any website.

Comment: Which line is the one that throws the error?

Comment: What is your Node.js version locally vs on the server?

Comment: jwt.sign(username, 'test', (err, token) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.sendStatus(403);
        }
    
        console.log(accessToken);
        res.json({accessToken: accessToken});
    });

This is the line that causes the error.

Comment: Woow im so dumb, i was using an older version of node on the server. Thanks for the reaction

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found out that the problem appeared when running the `npm audit fix` command to get rid of the vulnerabilities.

The process updated passport module and that seemed to be the cause of the problem. I went back to the settings before applying the fix and everything worked fine again.

Diff:

```
"passport": "~0.2.0",
"passport": "^0.6.0",

"passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
"passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
```

Fairly old node version:  10.16.0

I hope it helps

Comment: I am not using the passport module currently. Is it something you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I updated the node version on the server and it fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

Working with a new (to me) codebase. I keep running into this. I upgraded everything to the latest, but have the same errors.

```bash
$ grep jsonwebtoken package.json
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "9.0.1",

$ node --version
v19.6.0
```

deleted `node_modules`, ran `npm install` and restarted `npm run dev`

> TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

It's been over a day now, I can **really** do with some help here!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The issue being that version 9.0.0 of the jsonwebtoken package does not support node version 11 and below, so I solved it by downgrading the version of the jsonwebtoken package.

I did so by changing the jsonwebtoken dependency from 9.0.0 to 8.5.1 inside the package.json file, then I ran npm update inside my terminal.

Upgrading your node version might be recommended here, but I haven't quite managed to update my node version because of an npm issue, so this is only a workaround.

Checkout the following article explaining the migration from v8 to v9 of the jsonwebtoken package. https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/wiki/Migration-Notes:-v8-to-v9